# When page loads, default with text displayed on first link hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a gallery of cars in a ul and when you hover over each li (car) a list appears below. I'd like the first li's list to display when page loads as default. I have found ways to show an active li with javascript and css but that will only show the css I have for that li when I need the span I have in each li to appear.

example:

http://jsfiddle.net/cK6Y5/

HTML

```
<section id="brandSearch">
    <h2>今日看点</h2>
    <ul id="car-nav">

    <li id="car-01"><a href="#">小型车
    <span>
    <ul><li>帕萨特</li>
    <li>新轩逸</li>
    <li>奥迪A6L</li>
    <li>迈腾</li>
    <li>菲亚特500</li>
    <li>奥迪A4L</li>
    <li>宝马X3</li>
    <li>揽胜极光</li>
    <li>锐界</li>
    <li>爱唯欧</li>
    <li>嘉年华</li>
    <li>荣威W5</li>
    <li>POLO</li>
    <li>奥迪A1</li>
    <li>凯美瑞</li>
    <li>智跑</li>
    <li>斯柯达晶锐</li>
    </ul></span>
    </a></li>

    <li id="car-02"><a href="#">小型车<br>小型车

    <span>
    <ul><li>帕萨特</li>
    <li>新轩逸</li>
    <li>奥迪A6L</li>
    <li>迈腾</li>
    <li>菲亚特500</li>
    <li>奥迪A4L</li>
    <li>宝马X3</li>
    <li>揽胜极光</li>
    <li>锐界</li>
    <li>爱唯欧</li>
    <li>嘉年华</li>
    <li>荣威W5</li>
    <li>POLO</li>
    <li>奥迪A1</li>
    <li>凯美瑞</li>
    <li>智跑</li>
    <li>斯柯达晶锐</li>
    </ul></span>

    </a></li>

    <li id="car-03"><a href="#">家用车

    <span>
    <ul><li>帕萨特</li>
    <li>新轩逸</li>
    <li>奥迪A6L</li>
    <li>迈腾</li>
    <li>菲亚特500</li>
    <li>奥迪A4L</li>
    <li>宝马X3</li>
    <li>揽胜极光</li>
    <li>锐界</li>
    <li>爱唯欧</li>
    <li>嘉年华</li>
    <li>荣威W5</li>
    <li>POLO</li>
    <li>奥迪A1</li>
    <li>凯美瑞</li>
    <li>智跑</li>
    <li>斯柯达晶锐</li>
    </ul></span>

    </a></li>

    <li id="car-04"><a href="#">家用车

    <span>
    <ul><li>帕萨特</li>
    <li>新轩逸</li>
    <li>奥迪A6L</li>
    <li>迈腾</li>
    <li>菲亚特500</li>
    <li>奥迪A4L</li>
    <li>宝马X3</li>
    <li>揽胜极光</li>
    <li>锐界</li>
    <li>爱唯欧</li>
    <li>嘉年华</li>
    <li>荣威W5</li>
    <li>POLO</li>
    <li>奥迪A1</li>
    <li>凯美瑞</li>
    <li>智跑</li>
    <li>斯柯达晶锐</li>
    </ul></span>

    </a></li>

    <li id="car-05"><a href="#">豪华车

    <span>
    <ul><li>帕萨特</li>
    <li>新轩逸</li>
    <li>奥迪A6L</li>
    <li>迈腾</li>
    <li>菲亚特500</li>
    <li>奥迪A4L</li>
    <li>宝马X3</li>
    <li>揽胜极光</li>
    <li>锐界</li>
    <li>爱唯欧</li>
    <li>嘉年华</li>
    <li>荣威W5</li>
    <li>POLO</li>
    <li>奥迪A1</li>
    <li>凯美瑞</li>
    <li>智跑</li>
    <li>斯柯达晶锐</li>
    </ul></span>

    </a></li>

    <li id="car-06"><a href="#">豪华车

    <span>
    <ul><li>帕萨特</li>
    <li>新轩逸</li>
    <li>奥迪A6L</li>
    <li>迈腾</li>
    <li>菲亚特500</li>
    <li>奥迪A4L</li>
    <li>宝马X3</li>
    <li>揽胜极光</li>
    <li>锐界</li>
    <li>爱唯欧</li>
    <li>嘉年华</li>
    <li>荣威W5</li>
    <li>POLO</li>
    <li>奥迪A1</li>
    <li>凯美瑞</li>
    <li>智跑</li>
    <li>斯柯达晶锐</li>
    </ul></span>

    </a></li>

    <li id="car-07"><a href="#">跑车

    <span>
    <ul><li>帕萨特</li>
    <li>新轩逸</li>
    <li>奥迪A6L</li>
    <li>迈腾</li>
    <li>菲亚特500</li>
    <li>奥迪A4L</li>
    <li>宝马X3</li>
    <li>揽胜极光</li>
    <li>锐界</li>
    <li>爱唯欧</li>
    <li>嘉年华</li>
    <li>荣威W5</li>
    <li>POLO</li>
    <li>奥迪A1</li>
    <li>凯美瑞</li>
    <li>智跑</li>
    <li>斯柯达晶锐</li>
    </ul></span>

    </a></li>

    <li id="car-08"><a href="#">SUV

    <span>
    <ul><li>帕萨特</li>
    <li>新轩逸</li>
    <li>奥迪A6L</li>
    <li>迈腾</li>
    <li>菲亚特500</li>
    <li>奥迪A4L</li>
    <li>宝马X3</li>
    <li>揽胜极光</li>
    <li>锐界</li>
    <li>爱唯欧</li>
    <li>嘉年华</li>
    <li>荣威W5</li>
    <li>POLO</li>
    <li>奥迪A1</li>
    <li>凯美瑞</li>
    <li>智跑</li>
    <li>斯柯达晶锐</li>
    </ul></span>

    </a></li>

    <li id="car-09"><a href="#">SUV

    <span>
    <ul><li>帕萨特</li>
    <li>新轩逸</li>
    <li>奥迪A6L</li>
    <li>迈腾</li>
    <li>菲亚特500</li>
    <li>奥迪A4L</li>
    <li>宝马X3</li>
    <li>揽胜极光</li>
    <li>锐界</li>
    <li>爱唯欧</li>
    <li>嘉年华</li>
    <li>荣威W5</li>
    <li>POLO</li>
    <li>奥迪A1</li>
    <li>凯美瑞</li>
    <li>智跑</li>
    <li>斯柯达晶锐</li>
    </ul></span>

    </a></li>

    <li id="car-10"><a href="#">SUV

    <span>
    <ul><li>帕萨特</li>
    <li>新轩逸</li>
    <li>奥迪A6L</li>
    <li>迈腾</li>
    <li>菲亚特500</li>
    <li>奥迪A4L</li>
    <li>宝马X3</li>
    <li>揽胜极光</li>
    <li>锐界</li>
    <li>爱唯欧</li>
    <li>嘉年华</li>
    <li>荣威W5</li>
    <li>POLO</li>
    <li>奥迪A1</li>
    <li>凯美瑞</li>
    <li>智跑</li>
    <li>斯柯达晶锐</li>
    </ul></span>

    </a></li>

    <li id="car-11"><a href="#">皮卡

    <span>
    <ul><li>帕萨特</li>
    <li>新轩逸</li>
    <li>奥迪A6L</li>
    <li>迈腾</li>
    <li>菲亚特500</li>
    <li>奥迪A4L</li>
    <li>宝马X3</li>
    <li>揽胜极光</li>
    <li>锐界</li>
    <li>爱唯欧</li>
    <li>嘉年华</li>
    <li>荣威W5</li>
    <li>POLO</li>
    <li>奥迪A1</li>
    <li>凯美瑞</li>
    <li>智跑</li>
    <li>斯柯达晶锐</li>
    </ul></span>

    </a></li>
    </ul>


    </section><!--end brandSearch-->
```

CSS

```
#car-nav a span ul li {
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
font-size:90%;
line-height:10%;
}
#car-nav a span ul {
width:900px;
}
#car-02 ul {
margin-left:-90px;
}
#car-03 ul {
margin-left:-180px;
}
#car-04 ul {
margin-left:-270px;
}
#car-05 ul {
margin-left:-360px;
}
#car-06 ul {
margin-left:-450px;
}
#car-07 ul {
margin-left:-540px;
}
#car-08 ul {
margin-left:-620px;
}
#car-09 ul {
margin-left:-700px;
}
#car-10 ul {
margin-left:-770px;
}
#car-11 ul {
margin-left:-840px;
}

#car-01 { width: 90px; }
#car-02 { width: 90px; }
#car-03 { width: 90px; }
#car-04 { width: 90px; }
#car-05 { width: 90px; }
#car-06 { width: 90px; }
#car-07 { width: 80px; }
#car-08 { width: 80px; }
#car-09 { width: 70px; }
#car-10 { width: 70px; }
#car-11 { width: 80px; }
#car-01 a:hover { background: url(http://www.sarahtrafford.com/epochTimes/images/carsHover.jpg) no-repeat 0px -0px;
color:#BE191E;}
#car-02 a:hover { background:url(http://www.sarahtrafford.com/epochTimes/images/carsHover.jpg) -90px 0px no-repeat;   
color:#BE191E;}
#car-03 a:hover { background:url(http://www.sarahtrafford.com/epochTimes/images/carsHover.jpg) -180px 0px no-repeat; 
color:#BE191E;}
#car-04 a:hover { background:url(http://www.sarahtrafford.com/epochTimes/images/carsHover.jpg) -270px -0px no-repeat; 
color:#BE191E;}
#car-05 a:hover { background:url(http://www.sarahtrafford.com/epochTimes/images/carsHover.jpg) -360px -0px no-repeat; 
color:#BE191E;}
#car-06 a:hover { background:url(http://www.sarahtrafford.com/epochTimes/images/carsHover.jpg) -450px -0px no-repeat;   
color:#BE191E;}
#car-07 a:hover { background:url(http://www.sarahtrafford.com/epochTimes/images/carsHover.jpg) -540px -0px no-repeat; 
color:#BE191E;}
#car-08 a:hover { background:url(http://www.sarahtrafford.com/epochTimes/images/carsHover.jpg) -620px -0px no-repeat; 
color:#BE191E;}
#car-09 a:hover { background:url(http://www.sarahtrafford.com/epochTimes/images/carsHover.jpg) -700px -0px no-repeat; 
color:#BE191E;}
#car-10 a:hover { background:url(http://www.sarahtrafford.com/epochTimes/images/carsHover.jpg) -770px -0px no-repeat; 
color:#BE191E;}
#car-11 a:hover { background:url(http://www.sarahtrafford.com/epochTimes/images/carsHover.jpg) -840px -0px no-repeat; 
color:#BE191E;}
#car-nav {
width: 920px;
height: 123px;
margin-left: 15px;
padding: 0;
background-image: url(http://www.sarahtrafford.com/epochTimes/images/carNav.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position:relative;
}

#car-nav li, #car-nav a {
height: 25px;
display: block;
}

#car-nav li {
float: left;
list-style: none;
display: inline;
font-size:16px;
 }
#car-nav li a {
position: relative;
padding-top:60px;
padding-left:20px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#A2A2A2;
}
#car-nav li a span {
text-indent: 0em;
position: absolute;
top: 120px;
left:10px;
width: 900px;
text-align: justify;
display: none;
font-size:16px;
color:#BE191E;
padding-left:10px;
}

#car-nav li a:hover span {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to (and shouldn't) wrap your lists in `<span>` tags — `<span>` is used for inline elements, and a list is a block element. You can use `<div>` instead, or just not wrap the lists.

How about adding a `default` class to the first list and then styling it the same way you're styling `#car-nav li a:hover span`. Then, you can add a listener to your `#car-nav li a` elements to remove the default class on hover. Example using jQuery:

```
$('#car-nav li a').on('hover', function() {
    $('.default').removeClass('default');
});
```

Comment: The spans were the only way I could get that ul to display on hover. If I were to put in a div, wouldn't they all display on default?

Comment: It would normally, but you can use CSS to hide those elements by default just like you've done with the spans. You might need to set their display to `inline-block` to match the default formatting of a span.

Comment: when I try this it shows the div and displays it in the wrong area, sorry I don't understand how to make that way work

Comment: Did you update your CSS to select on `div` instead of `span`?

Comment: yes I did, I removed the span class so it read: #car-nav a ul li instead of #car-nav span ul li

Comment: What about `#car-nav div`?

Comment: ya, I tried that too and the divs automatically display. I'd have to hide them but then they won't show when I hover..

Answer (score 0):

I agree with OverlappingElvis: div should replace your spans.
With your actuel spans, you add something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#car-01 span").css('display', 'block');
});
```

to adapt if you replace span tags by div ones.

Comment: This did work however (since I'm not great at java script) I'm not sure how to hide once you hover over another li

Comment: Maybe by adding in your css : #car-nav li a span {display: none;}

Comment: that just removes it completely